# Array of Instances with constructors

Tags: c++, arrays, class, initialization

I have a class `F` that has a constructor like this:

```
public:
  F(int N){
    Tree = new int[N];
  }
```

I want to create an array that contains 26 instances of `F`

If the constructor had no arguments, I could have just done `F ArrayOfF[26]`

However, this constructor does have an argument and something along the lines `F(N) ArrayOfF[26]` is not working.

What is a good way to do this?

Comment: [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)

Comment: Are you suggesting I use std::vector to push the instances one by one? Is there no good way to do it with simple arrays?

Comment: You should also be using `std::vector` inside the class for Tree as well ... (And std::vector is awesome because this `std::vector<F> ArrayOfF(26, F(N))` )

Comment: @AgnishomChattopadhyay I am suggesting that you replace the array with a vector so you can make it whatever size you need

Comment: @AgnishomChattopadhyay Just `std::vector<F> v(26, F(99));`

Answer (score 2):

One option is to be explicit:

```
F ArrayOfF[26] = {
    F(1), F(2), F(3), F(4), F(5), F(6), F(7), F(8), F(9), F(10),
    F(1), F(2), F(3), F(4), F(5), F(6), F(7), F(8), F(9), F(20),
    F(1), F(2), F(3), F(4), F(5), F(6)
};
```

`std::vector` is a good options too.

```
std::vector<F> ArrayOfF(26, F(42));
```

or

```
std::vector<F> ArrayOfF;
ArrayOfF.reserve(26); // Optional: to do only one allocation.
for (int i = 0; i != 26; ++i) {
    ArrayOfF.push_back(F(2 * i + 5));
}
```